# Watching changes in typeahead [angularjs+bootstrap]

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i have two  typeahead .first one shows all account groups .

second one should show ledgers which are listed based on the selection of first typeahed.

this is first typeahead

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="newItem.customSelected1" typeahead="account_group as account_group.group_name for account_group in account_groups | filter:{group_name:$viewValue}"/>
```

this is second typeahead.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="newItem.customSelected2" typeahead="ledger as ledger.ledger_name for ledger in ledgers | filter:{ledger_name:$viewValue}"/>
```

i have tried ng-change but that does not provide me solution.

**update**

i have tried like this

```
$scope.$watch("newItem.customSelected1", function (newItem.customSelected1) {
    if(newItem.customSelected2='abc')
    console.log(newItem.customSelected2);


    });
```

but this does not giving te solution. please help

Comment: Should be able to just apply another filter before the one using the $viewValue which filters based on the value in the model that was selected in the first input.

Comment: can u explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       required
       ng-model="newItem.customSelected2"
       typeahead="ledger as ledger.ledger_name for ledger in ledgers | filter:newItem.customSelected1.ledger | filter:{ledger_name:$viewValue}"/>
```

Or depending on how you structure your data just something like this would be good

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       required
       ng-model="newItem.customSelected2"
       typeahead="ledger as ledger.ledger_name for ledger in newItem.customSelected1.ledgers | filter:{ledger_name:$viewValue}"/>
```

But this depends in part on your data model, including that will help get a more concrete answer.  Also including a plunkr to show your problems in action is always better:

[http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl%3aFrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f)

Comment: based on the value from typeahead1 i have to call fetch new value fromdb. how to do that?

Comment: In the docs for angularui see typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label) once that gets called you can make your $http call to get the data for the second list.

Comment: Generally speaking I tend to eager load tons of data in Angular because it can deal with it fine so long as you don't go crazy with the DOM